# How can I find html file in Inspect Element

Tags: javascript, php, html

sorry for my English
I'm using mibew messenger that is open source, I want to change title of chat page and need find source of related page to edit by using Inspect Element.   . would you help me how can i do ?
[image: Insepect Element in google chrome]

looking forward to your responses
thanks
Solmaz

Comment: you have to click on logo

Comment: using inspector select div and then at styles tab at right at element.style{} enter your css

Comment: for html data change at html source an enter

Comment: well, I must not understand the question, because I certainly don't understand the randomness of the comments!

Comment: I would try to find it by classes of element you need to change, then ctrl+shift+f. Another approach is to add into every HTML file some line of code with comment and and filename <!-- start of file header.phtml --> <!-- end of file header.phtml-->

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really programming related but rather asks help for "hacking away" some HTML